# how to obtain leaf count (expression size) in sage?

Tags: sage

(I did not know there is sage group at stackoverflow. I asked this before at sage support usenet, but that is very slow).

Here is the question:

Is there a way in sage to determine the size of expression as given typically by leaf count? Similar to what is documented in Mathematica `leafCount[]` here

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html

"gives the total number of indivisible subexpressions in expr."

And also similar to Maple's

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MmaTranslator/Mma/LeafCount&term=leafcount

I need a way to measure the size of resulting expression from sage to compare it with Mathematica's result and Maple's as well. I currently use leafCount() for this since both Maple and Mathematica have this function.

Does sage have similar function or another way to obtain this measure?

For example, given this expression

```
 (c + integrate(e^(2*x + sin(x)), x))*e^(-sin(x))
```

Then in Mathematica I would write

```
  Clear[x, c];
  expr = (c + Integrate[Exp[2*x + Sin[x]], x])*Exp[-Sin[x]];
  LeafCount[expr]

          19
```

Update:
To answer the question below on how the leaves are counted. If one draws a tree expression, then it is each node in the expression tree. For the above, it is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly, `LeafCount[x + y]` gives 3 since

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Asked again as [Ask Sage question 57123](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/57123) which now has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not built in, though perhaps it should be.  As long as you are comfortable writing your own tree traversal, the discussions [here](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/9329) and [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/9614/getting-a-rooted-graph-from-a-nested-list-of-lists/) should be helpful.

Here is a wrong implementation that should help you.  It is wrong because I don't get 19 - basically, I get the number of constants and `x`s, which is not what you want.  I don't know how such subexpressions are counted.  But I think using a combination of `expr.operands()` and `expr.operator()` will get what you are looking for.

```
def tree(expr): 
    if expr.operator() is None: 
        return expr 
    else: 
        return map(tree, expr.operands()) 

expr = (x + integrate(e^(2*x + sin(x)), x))*e^(-sin(x))
len(flatten(tree(expr)))
```

Edit: If a leaf is really any node (not just leaves in the graph theory sense, which seems odd), then [probably something here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/9614/getting-a-rooted-graph-from-a-nested-list-of-lists/) is indeed useful.  Not my code:

```
sage: def tree(expr): 
....:         if expr.operator() is None: 
....:                 return expr 
....:         else: 
....:                 return [expr.operator()]+map(tree, expr.operands()) 
....:     
sage: var('y')
y
sage: tree(x+y)
[<function operator.add>, x, y]
sage: tree((y+integrate(e^(2*x+sin(x)),x))*e^(-sin(x)))
[<function operator.mul>,
 [<function operator.add>,
  y,
  [integrate,
   [exp, [<function operator.add>, [<function operator.mul>, x, 2], [sin, x]]],
   x]],
 [exp, [<function operator.mul>, [sin, x], -1]]]
sage: len(tree((y+integrate(e^(2*x+sin(x)),x))*e^(-sin(x))))
3
sage: len(flatten(tree((y+integrate(e^(2*x+sin(x)),x))*e^(-sin(x)))))
17
```

You'll notice that the answer is different because Sage counts `exp` as a primitive operator, not `e^stuff`.

See also the [answer to your sage-support question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/Vx0gq5t167w).